# What are the APIs needed to build disabled web part in TFS 2018?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, sharepoint-2010

Hi since TFS has disabled the following web parts like Recent Build Web part, Project Work Item Web part, Recent Checkins and TSF web parts - query based-lists. What are the API needed to build and the problems it might occur when using the API to build that?

Thank you

I am aware of this webparts disabled

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/features-removed-when-disabling-sharepoint-integration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Beginning with TFS 2018, the features that the TFS Extension for
>   SharePoint provided will no longer be available. But TFS offers
>   [built-in dashboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/dashboards/dashboards). Each TFS team can create any number of
>   dashboards to meet their needs.
>
> We will continue to invest in our built-in dashboards solution. We
>   continue to develop widgets to provide instant insights into your
>   data. Additionally, you can find widgets developed by our partners in
>   the [VSTS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=widgets&target=VSTS&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance).
>
> In the future, we will provide ways of displaying our built-in
>   dashboards on SharePoint pages.

Of course TFS provides rich API to meet various requirements, you could check them from here:

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

Comment: Can i know which API to use for recent builds and recent check ins from the link you provided? I don't know which one to use for them

Comment: Check https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#get-a-list-of-builds and https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#get-list-of-changesets. Results are sorted by ID in descending order by default. You can use $top parameter to return maximum number of builds/changeset.

Comment: What API to use for toolbar?

Comment: What's toolbar?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/report/sharepoint-dashboards/deprecation/features-removed-when-disabling-sharepoint-integration refer to this link, they disabled the toolbar.